How to "lock a table for a user" / make sure an action / route is not called twice / in paralell in laravel
I'm basically looking for a way to lock the table for the user inbetween the select and until after all inserts in order to make sure that when the select is executed a second time, the entries already exist.
Assuming I have a route like
Route::get('/initialize', [MyController::class, 'init']);

Where the logic is like
$transactions = Transaction::where('generated_until', '<', Carbon::now())->get();
$transactions ->each(function ($transaction) use ($generateUntil) {
  Auth::user()->transactions()->create([
    // some data
    'generated_until' => Carbon::now()->addMonth()
  ]);
});

I am facing the problem that if this route is called twice (in parallell) the entries will be generated twice.

What you are looking for is Pessimistic Locking where you lock a row to you. Try to check this docs: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queries#pessimistic-locking

Do you know any resource with more details on how the lock works? What happens if a second call is done? Will it fail or will it wait until the transaction is commited?

I think it will give an error? Might be better to add a try/catch block + DB::transaction to make sure.
